# Anyway to "reset" a group imesssage?

Tags: iphone, messages

I'm having a bit of and odd problem with a group message, likely due to a bit of weird history with this groupchat. Rough outline below (this may include extraneous data)

I have a groupchat with two other people, a and b. Originally all three of us had non-apple phones. Eventually b switched to an iphone, and later myself and a did too. The groupmessage was semi-persisted through all of this, and everything seemed fine for the duration of all of us having iphones. Finally, b switched away from (the now-imessage) groupchat to an android phone. Suddenly, the groupchat no longer worked -- B was unable to receive messages, and deleting and restarting the groupchat didn't seem to help.

My intuition says that apple thinks b still has an iphone and somehow this results in him not receiving text messages, but I've been unable to fix this problem and haven't found useful data online.

Anyone experience something similar/have any suggestions? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using B's phone number or email address for that chat?  Did either change when B changed devices?  Take a look at [this Apple Support doc](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204270) and see if it helps.  Also, make sure B [deactivated](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351) their Messages.

Comment: Hey @fsb, thanks for taking the time to respond! Using phone number and no, neither changed with device. I believe he tried that, but I'll bother him to do it again. Do you have any idea on what the internals of the imessage/non-imessage boolean looks like?

Comment: No, i don't.  I just know you need to [deregister your device](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203042) when moving to a non-Apple phone.  If B didn't do that, it could be the root of the issue.  B needs to stop Messages from being associated with their phone number.

Comment: This seems plausible... Thanks for the help. I'll update above if this doesn't resolve anything.

Comment: Let me know if this works and I'll add it as an answer to help others.

Comment: @fsb -- ended up using your strategy, but a couple of other things were required [removing name from groupchat weirdly seemed important]. Thanks again for help!